# What View Google Plus used to show Collection and Communities?

Tags: android, user-interface, google-plus

Is this Vertical Scrollable Gallery or Vertical Scrollable Grid View? As i go through many Q&A in SOF, but I got to know that Vertical Scrolling is not allowed in Gallery. 
I want to know how to create a View like Google Plus.

[image]

Comment: That specifically is probably a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. You could also do it with a `GridView`, if you don't want to mess with a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: But is this possiblt to have only 2 Columns in GridView?

Comment: Yeah. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Ohh.. thanks Mike. Yeahh it will be.. :)